# How to Stop Keyboard Listener after a particular time?

Tags: python, pynput

I have a Function which keep listening.. I want to stop the Listener after a particular time

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

with Listner(on_press=onPress) as l:
    l.join
```

this is an Endless Loop... i want to Stop the listener after a particular time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from threading import Thread


def on_press(key):
    print(f"Key pressed: {key}")


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as ls:
    def time_out(period_sec: int):
        time.sleep(period_sec)  # Listen to keyboard for period_sec seconds
        ls.stop()

    Thread(target=time_out, args=(5.0,)).start()
    ls.join()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
from threading import Timer

from pynput.keyboard import Listener


def on_press(key):
    print(key)


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as l:
    Timer(5, l.stop).start()
    l.join()
    print('5 seconds passed')
```

Comment: How could someone stop and start the stream?  For instance say you need to get the keyboard's buttons every two minutes

Comment: Just move the code into function and call it whenever needed.